# How To add ..Read More in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

I have an UIView in this view there is a UILabel in some cases the text is longer than the UILabel height itself.

So basically my requirement is I have to add a *...Read More text after two lines in UILabel* and when someone tapped at Read More, the label expands as per height of its text and "Read More" changed to "Read Less"

If the text in UILabel is less then 2 lines then "Read More" should be hidden.

Comment: Maybe this lib helpful for you: https://github.com/manicmaniac/MMCollapsibleLabel

Comment: Make the `UILabel` autoresizable and use short text and full texts to change the `label`'s height according to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first set the number of line = 1 or 2 which you want for show more button. 
Like as

```
self.yourLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
self.yourLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
self.yourLabel?.sizeToFit()
```

then on show more button click set

```
self.yourLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
self.yourLabel?.sizeToFit()
```

if you used same button for both show less and show more than also maintain one boolean flag.
or For different ShowLess button click set the number of line to 2